# Basic logic components in Restcomm Apps

Tags: voip, mobicents, restcomm

I don't see a way in Restcomm  Apps using RVD to create basic data or basic logic trees. Is there a way to create components for:

- Creating and assigning variable values
- Basic logic components such as If Then Else, Equal / Not Equal, Contains, Comparisons for Text, Numbers, Dates,
- The ability to parse text using Regex
- The ability to insert variables into any value and have them parsed correctly
- String concatenation or similar

Components such as these would allow an app developer to have many more self-contained apps instead of having to stand up infrastructure to manage all of the app logic.

Does the current component API support the development of new components?

Answer (score 1):

@scottbarstow

At the moment Restcomm RVD doesn't provide most of the features you mentioned out of the box. However, it is possible to achieve your goal using Restcomm RVD External Services. The variables, logic, regex parsing, etc will be handled using an external programming language of your choice.

Another option will be to use the [Restcomm-ruby helper](https://github.com/Mobicents/restcomm-ruby) to build your application. The basic app will be to built using Restcomm Visual Designer and then you can make a call to the app using the Restcomm-ruby helper. All the (If Then Else, Equal / Not Equal etc.) will be handle by the Restcomm-ruby helper.

You could always send an RFE to Telestax.

Comment: Unless I am missing something, all the Ruby helper does is provide a wrapper for the API.  It doesn't introduce new functionality into the RVD / App framework.  I can build external apps to do all of this, that's not a problem.  However, in many cases I may as well just direct all interactions to that app and not even build an app.  I can just configure the app urls for the numbers as usual and forward them all off.

Answer (score 1):

RVD has resulted out of a struggle between offering as much flexibility to the user and spending as little development effort as possible while following an iterative approach. It evolved with small steps in order to have a functional progressing application always. In order to honor these requirements, a very crucial design decision was made: to keep the core part (the controller) a dummy engine that simply produces RCML and delegate all logic somewhere else, easily accessible over HTTP.

That being said, @scottbarstow, i welcome your comments. Having self contained apps greatly simplifies the setup and maintenance of an application, especially now that RAS is emerging. ES should be a tool to talk to really external targets not a way to delegate all sorts of complex operations outside RVD.

However, "logic" comes at a high cost. Introducing several elements for branching, comparisons, string manipulation etc. needs a lot of thinking to be designed, hours to be implemented and headaches to be debugged.

The alternative approach i suggest is the following:

> 1. Improve the way ES talks to external endpoints. Add full support for
>    submitting POST/JSON payload. Have a choice of choosing between
>    application/json and url-encoded forms content types. Handle
>    everything else that is typically required by common service providers
>    like Slack. All processing will be done in the ES. Further feedback
>    here would be appreciated.
> 2. Keep all logic in a single place instead of spreading it across
>    several new elements. Introduce the "Script" element where some sort
>    of scripting engine will be used to execute a block of code
>    implementing all required logic. Let this element talk to the outside
>    world through  a simple string-based contract with "INs" and "OUTs".
>    There is already an experimental implementation on that using **Groovy**
>    and the same could be done with server side **Javascript**.
>
> *But, wait a minute. RVD is supposed to be a simple tool for common users, not developers!*
> *Well, indeed. But consider the alternative. Will it be easier to understand and use a number of new smart elements and all the added syntax implications that will come with it? I guess not unless its very basic. Let alone debugging and support.*
>
> Javascript has a well known syntax and it is much easier to debug. It even runs inside the browser which opens the window for client side testing.
>
> 3. Introduce a very basic branching/GOTO element. It will be able to break module execution and redirect to another module. The logic of
>    branching however will be implemented in a previous Script element.

**Technical shortcomings and "why logic should be kept in a single black-box place"**

RVD has state. There are variables it creates (Collect, ES elements create such) in addition to these fed by Restcomm that need to be preserved. Since the application flow progresses as a series of restcomm originating action requests that are stateless by nature there are two options.

(a) Recycle these variable in the action URLs or

(b) Store them in an session-like structure in RVD and keep a session-id  that gets transferred instead.

RVD uses (a).

That means whenever control is passed back to restcomm (like when a Gather/Collect element is executed) all this state needs to be encoded in the action URL contained in the response. That way when restcomm makes the next request RVD will have the state. Its more or less the same pattern with old-school web dev with no HTTP session.

This state needs to be *small* in order not to have a lot of  data going back and forth between RVD and Restcomm.

An RVD application consists of modules that contain elements that are processed sequentially and any element can potentially break the app execution in RVD and return control back to restcomm. It makes sense to make elements independent so that  there is an  option to break the application execution and return control back  to Restcomm.

My point is that we need to keep elements independent, the interface between an element and the RVD execution context simple and the state easily serializable. And a block-box like Script element seems  to fit this goal.

Comment: I think a scripting thing would work. I did this with a product a few years ago where we allowed users to write Javascript to handle any and all logic, and then we executed the script in a walled off V8 VM.  There are a number of issues with this approach, namely:

- Controlling what can and can't be done in the script and checking for violations (preventing abuse in other words)
- Debugging / exposing errors in a meaningful / obvious way
- Exposing the application entities to the JS runtime in a way that makes sense

Comment: Furthermore...

- Siloing the execution via something like a jailed V8 VM as we did.  If you let someone write javascript, devs will do everything they can to find holes in your approach.

I would argue that, if the tool is supposed to be easy for non developer users, then having more components and not a scripting language makes more sense.

The scripting solution is obviously far more powerful.

Comment: I haven't worked with server-side javascript embeded in Java, but i would expect it to be jailed by definition. In contrast with say, Groovy that is a general purpose language and it would seem almost impossible to make secure. There can be CPU and RAM resources issues however that can easily bring the system to its knees.

Answer (score 0):

Enabling scripting into RVD is relatively straightforward. However it is not clear what is a good way to deal with application code bugs. Inexperienced developers can shoot themselves in the foot pretty quick with dynamic, loosely typed scripting languages.

The original intention of RVD was to make simple real time communication apps really easy and fool proof to create. Its still an open question whether the scope of RVD should expand to make more complex things possible or defer those to external services.

Can we look closer at the app you are trying to implement? If the intention is to take an SMS or a voice call recording and send it to a third party service such as Slack, that could be achieved through a service like Zapier. See the attached screenshots that illustrate connection from a WordPress plug-in (Gravity Forms) to Slack.

Would a similar Zapier module for Restcomm (in place of Gravity Forms) help?

[image: Gravity form to Slack connection]

[image: Conditional data integration]

Comment: You can of course branch to other services easily.  But if you think about this as a developer of an application, you introduce a good deal of complexity.

For everyone who installs the app, do they then need a Zapier account or some other credentials to make it work?  At the very least you have to enable access in some way to all of the other touch points for each customer who downloads your app.

The question really is:  Is RVD designed to just be a bridge from telephony to everything else or is it designed to be a more rich app platform.  Either is fine, but they're very different messages.

Comment: Indeed. The first priority for RVD was to make it dead simple to bridge any telephony network to modern apps. Now that's mostly accomplished, we can venture a bit further into the layer of app hosting to minimize the moving parts that developers have to deal with for common apps.